# Access Violation in Qt postEvent

Tags: c++, qt, access-violation

I have an application that is starting to throw fits at various points.  It was written ages ago using one of the first versions of the Qt library.  Love to update it but that's not in the cards yet.  While testing a part of the app, I received an unexpected crash:

```
Unhandled exception at 0x00a220db in MyApp.exe: 
0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000000.
```

The application code that I can see (the Qt lib source code is not available for debugging so it's just a disassembly).

```
MyEvent myEvent = new MyEvent(str1, int, str2);
QApplication::postEvent(parent(), myEvent);
```

Call stack at the affected area:

```
    MyApp.exe!QGList::append()  + 0x6b bytes    
    MyApp.exe!QList<QPostEvent>::append()  + 0x2f bytes 
    MyApp.exe!QApplication::postEvent()  + 0x55a bytes  
>   MyApp.exe!SomeClass::writeTestName(const char * format=0x00f6c2b8, ...)  Line 386 + 0x15 bytes
```

If I examine myEvent and parent(), both appear to be valid. What is the postEvent method adding my event to and, assuming it's a Qt internal, which it appears to be, why would it fail - is there some initialization that needs to be done that the original programmer might have missed?

Comment: ***0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000000.*** Dereferenceing a null pointer.

Comment: I know that, but, what pointer would it be?  It's a Qt internal, as far as I can tell.  I'm not familiar with the Qt model so I am unsure if there's an init method that needs to be called at some point to set up the internals.

Comment: ***I am unsure if there's an init method that needs to be called at some point to set up the internals.*** I would say probably not. Although I started my Qt development at 4.5. Not sure what version you are talking about here.

Comment: Copyright 1992-2000, if that gives any indication of it's vintage.

Comment: Maybe parent() is not valid anymore when the event is handled. Can you try sendEvent()?